# not open my Magento connect manager

Tags: magento-1.9, error, magento-connect-manager

> Connection string invalid:
>   'ftp://example:password@example.com/public_html/'

This is error message in magento connect manage page.
What seems to be the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the permission of `downloader` folder to `755` and check.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 downloader/
```

and be sure that your `chown` should be `www-data`

let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....